# Applying a method to multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

```
test "pass this test" do
  @item_one.change
  @item_two.change
  @item_one.reload
  @item_two.reload
  assert @item_one.changed?
  assert @item_two.changed?
end
```

My attempt to DRY this out

```
test "pass this test" do
  (@item_one, @item_two).change
  (@item_one, @item_two).reload
  assert (@item_one, @item_two).changed?
end
```

Obviously doesn't work because we'd be calling the method on an array. Meanwhile, a loop seems too tedious for 2 objects.

What am I looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
test "pass this test" do
  [@item_one, @item_two].each(&:change)
  [@item_one, @item_two].each(&:reload)
  assert [@item_one, @item_two].map(&:changed?).all?
end
```

`each(&:...)` is shortcut of `each do ... end` and
`map(&:...)` is shortcut of `map do ... end`.

Comment: The last line probably wouldn't work. `each` will just return the original array (unlike `map`) and you'll be aserting an array, which will probably be true. You could do: `assert [@item_one, @item_two].map(&:changed?).all?` which will return boolean—true if all the elements in the array are true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want exists exactly. The closest thing I can think of is

```
[@item_one, @item_two].map {|x| x.change }
```